# Gradle: Exclude from compile, but still have Autocompletion

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

First of all some background:

I'm currently refactoring our application for Internal Tools and Scripts, and got into 'beauty problems' some would call it.

The base structure of the application should not include the scripts that are being created, those will be downloaded by the application on request. Imagine it like an AppStore for Internal Tools.

But to give developers in the new repository the Option to create those scripts, with auto completion, I'm searching for a way to include an external folder to the indexed files in IntelliJ, that doesn't add the whole folder to the compile task.

Folder structure is like that:

```
(1) ./ScriptSuite/scripts/
(2) ./src/main/
```

Where in (2) are all the backend sources, including Utilities and database connections etc. And in (1) are groovy script files, that can be loaded dynamically on request.

I want to avoid having the scripts in (2) cause this led to confusion earlier, because sometimes we couldn't differ if it's a script compiled at app start or a script downloaded from our server after app start.

I tried adding (1) to the build.gradle via:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs {
                'src/main/groovy'
            }
            srcDir {
                'ScriptSuite/scripts'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then the Files would be included in the compilation at App Start, which I'm trying to avoid, since those should be compiled at runtime by the GroovyScriptEngine. Also (1) is excluded from push into the repository, we host those on our S3 Bucket and other tools are in place for version control.

What did work, was adding (1) as a module source folder in IntelliJ itself, but this is only client side and won't get pushed into the repository, so everyone would have to configure it for himself (not good).

Any idea how to solve this problem with gradle ? I appreciate every help or tip !